# MySQL 8.0.34 Community Server Can't open shared library '/usr/lib64/mysql/plugin/audit_log.so' undefined symbol: my_charset_utf8_general_ci)

Tags: mysql

I am a newbie on MySQL security-related things particularly, a few months ago I got to know about the MySQL audit plugin to audit the events. I did some research and I got to know that it's for the enterprise version of MySQL only. I installed and it worked perfectly fine. Now I have a local environment setup already where I am using MySQL Community server 8.0.34. and copied the audit_plugin.so from the enterprise version server to the community server. Can someone please guide me is it even possible to achieve this or not?

The server that has Enterprise MySQL installed it SQL version is 8.0.33 and OS is CentOS 7.

I am getting this error. **ERROR 1126 (HY000) at line 8: Can't open shared library '/usr/lib64/mysql/plugin/audit_log.so' (errno: 2 /usr/lib64/mysql/plugin/audit_log.so: undefined symbol: m**y_charset_utf8_general_ci)

**OS version:**
NAME="CentOS Linux"
VERSION="7 (Core)"
ID="centos"
ID_LIKE="rhel fedora"
VERSION_ID="7"
PRETTY_NAME="CentOS Linux 7 (Core)"

**MySQL version:**

MySQL  Ver 8.0.34 for Linux on x86_64 (MySQL Community Server - GPL)

**I need help to install it. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks in advance**